# Is it really true that magento does not swap out the images according to the attribute selected on the front end?

Tags: product-images

i was really surprised to find this an issue. i am in an older vs 1.6. is there a way to get magento to show a red shirt when the color red is selected and blue when the blue attribute is selected? seems very basic for magento to pull the image from the associated product!

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It's true.
But there are a lot of extensions out there that do this.
Here are a few.

- https://github.com/tzyganu/Switcher - this one is mine that's why I put it first. :). I didn't test it on 1.6 but it might work.
- http://amasty.com/color-swatches-pro.html
- http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/simple-configurable-products.html
- http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/color-swatches-magento-extension.html

I know some of them are not free, but they are a lot cheaper than developing them yourself.